# Is there any way to prove that the following space is a $2$-dimensional embedding manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, compact-manifolds

How I can prove that:

$X := \{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^3 + y^3 + z^3 − 3xyz =1\}$
 is a embedded manifold that $2$-dimensional  in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: By applying the regular value theorem.

Comment: It seems that all points of the form $(t,\sqrt[3]{1-t^3},0)$ are in $X$.  If so, I don't think $X$ can be compact.

Comment: Matthew Leingang,  please can you write to me all the stages of your way for understanding?

Comment: Use the fact that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded: since $X$ is the set of zeroes of a continuous function is it clearly closed, but it cannot be bounded by the remark of Matthew.

Comment: Are you certain you copied the question properly?

Comment: yes,I want a help  to show that the space $X$ above is  an embedded manifold 2-dimensional in $R^3$.

Comment: Sila, in the body of your question you have a question correctly stated. However, the title part of your question includes the word "compact," which is false for the surface indicated.

Comment: Ah...if we're removing the word "compact," then (1) it's possible that the claim is true, and (2) it's likely that the "regular value theorem" mentioned by @LeeMosher is the way to show it. That theorem is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem. The function to apply it to is $f(x, y, z) = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 − 3xyz -1.$ You'll want to show that $f^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold (which will automatically be of dimension $2$) of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I saw that. If I were asking the question, I'd be sure to make the $3xyz$ term involve, say, $\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x$, so as to make certain such a thing wasn't possible, and you *had* to use the regular-value theorem. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes, how we compute the $f^-1$ in $R^3$? I forget how to compute it  in $R^3$. Can you remember me ?

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer, but a hint**

Lee Mosher has advised using the regular value theorem to prove the assertion. I've observed that what's needed is to show that for 
$$
f(x, y, z) = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz -1
$$
the set $M = f^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold.

OP asks "How do we compute $f^{-1}$ in $\Bbb R^3$?"

If OP means "what's a formula for $f^{-1}$?", the answer is that there isn't one: for a given value in $\Bbb R$ like, say, $0$, there are many points with $f(x, y, z) = 0$. For instance, $f(1,0,0) = f(0,1,0) = f(0,0,1) = 0$. So there's no formula (or even any *function* taking $0 \in \Bbb R$ to a single point $f^{-1}(0) \in \Bbb R^3$.

On the other hand, there is a preimage of $0$ in $\Bbb R^3$ --- it's the set of all triples that are sent to zero. In other words, $f^{-1}(0)$ is *defined* to mean
$$
M = \{(a, b, c) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid f(a, b, c) = 0 \}.
$$

Maybe $OP$ was asking, "Yes, but how do I actually *find* that set, because to apply the theorem, I have to show that for every point $(a,b,c)$ in that set, the derivative is nonsingular, so I have to know all the points!"

That's the clever part of this kind of question: often you don't have to be able to explicitly write down every element. To show that the derivative is nonsingular at some point $(a,b,c)$, it's often sufficient to know that $f(a,b,c) = 0$.

Let me do an example. I'm going to prove that the unit circle in the plane is a 1-manifold, using the regular value theorem. I let
$$
g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1
$$
and I claim that $S = g^{-1}(0)$ is a 1-manifold. To show this using the theorem, I need to show that $dg(a,b)$ has rank $1$ for every point $(a,b) \in S$.

I could do this easily by just writing down all the point (using sine and cosine), but I'm going to do it *without* that. Here goes.

At any point $(x, y)$, $dg(x, y) = (2x, 2y)$. So for a point $(a, b) \in S$, we have $dg(a, b) = (2a, 2b)$. We want to show that this $1 \times 2$ matrix has rank $1$. So suppose that for some $(a,b) \in S$, we have that $(a,b)$ has rank $0$ instead of rank $1$. A rank-zero $1 \times 2$ matrix must be the zero vector, so we have
$$
(2a, 2b) = (0,0)
$$
from which we conclude that $a = b = 0$, which is a contradiction, because we know that $g(a, b) = a^2 + b^2 - 1$ is zero, but $g(0,0) = 0^2 + 0^2 - 1 = -1$. Hence for $(a,b) \in g^{-1}(0)$, we have that $dg(a,b)$ is rank 1, so $g^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold.

Comment: ,thanks to your help!

Comment: in the case of function #f# above , the rank of the matrix of d(f)is 2?

Comment: That's indeed what you want to prove. You only need to prove it, however, at *points in the set $f^{-1}(0)$*, the thing that is supposed to be a surface.  If you were to evaluate $df(0,0,0)$, for instance, you would not get a rank-two matrix, but that;'s OK, because $(0,0,0)$ is not in the set $f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: I arrive to that for any point (x,y,z), df(x,y,z)=(3x^2-3yz, 3y^2-3xz, 3z^2-3xy). and so for a point (a,b,c)∈M, I have df(a,b,c)=(3a^2-3bc, 3b^2-3ac, 3c^2-3ab).

Comment: if  rank-zero 1×3 matrix  is  the zero vector, so a=b=c=0 and this a  contradiction. but how I also must to show that  the rank  of  1×3 matrix is not 1?

Comment: I'm an idiot ... I'd forgotten, over the intervening weeks, what was what. My apologies I should have said that you still want to prove that the rank of $df$ is **one**, not **two**. So to prove that $df(a,b,c)$ has rank $1$, what do you have to show?

Comment: ,is it enoוgh to show that the rank is 1 for showing that the dimesion of a embedded manifold is 2?

Comment: What  the connction between rank and deminsion?

Comment: i.e. if I have a linear function mapping R3 -> R then the column space of the matrix representing this function will have dimension 2, and the rank of the matrix df must be 1, is it right?

Comment: I know that the dimension is the number of bases in the column space of the matrix representing a linear function between two spaces.

Comment: I think perhaps you need to read the statement of the theorem very carefully: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem . It explicitly describes the relationship between rank and dimension.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of  codeminsion?

Comment: Then perhaps you should search for the definition.

Comment: ok now I understand the theorem,can you take me a hint to show that X is not compacted?

Comment: I must show that X is not closed and is not bounded by  Heine–Borel theorem.right?

Comment: You must show that *either* it's not closed *or* it's not bounded, or both. (This'll be my last response here; at this point, you're on your own.)

Comment: thank you for a help:)